# Composite C1 MVC Function - Data Annotations aren't being rendered into page

Tags: c1-cms

Trying to use the MVC Function (http://docs.composite.net/Functions/MVC/MVC-Functions), and when we run our standalone MVC App, the Data Annotations are appearing on the form controls, but when use the MVC Function feature on a C1 page, the control and value will render just fine, but the data annotations are missing.

**Our View Model in the MVC App**

```
[EmailAddress]
[StringLength(255)]
[Required]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

**Inside the view (.cshtml) used for the MVC Function**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AcctInfo.Email)
```

**Rendered in the C1 page.**

```
<input id="AcctInfo_Email" name="AcctInfo.Email" type="text" value="foo@test.com" >
```

**This is the MVC Web App page (outside of C1)**

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-email="The Email field is not a valid e-mail address." 
data-val-length="The field Email must be a string with a maximum length of 255." data-val-length-max="255"
data-val-required="The Email field is required." id="AcctInfo_Email" name="AcctInfo.Email" 
type="text" value="foo@test.com">
```

Is it possible to use Data Annotations in Composite C1 MVC Functions?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. The web.config for the C1 project needed the following.

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
```